# Change the application name at runtime on Mac for a JavaFX-based App

Tags: macos, javafx-2

Please take a look at this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFKKg.png
Is it possible to change the application name ("My JavaFX-based Mac App") in the Mac OS X system menu bar at runtime after the app starts?
If it's not possible to change at runtime, is there a way to change it after app restarts?
I think that name came from Info.plist.
The app is built using JavaFX ant task for Mac OS X.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you get it to display **My JavaFX-based Mac App**? I was unable to find how to change it from the default, **Java**.

Comment: I see just 'Java' too when I run the app from within an IDE (Eclipse).
To get it to display a custom name, I use the JavaFX Ant Task to build a Mac application bundle.  In the <fx:application> tag of the Ant build script, I set the name attribute to 'My JavaFX-based Mac App'.  http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/javafx_ant_tasks.htm#CIACDJHC has more info about creating an app bundle.

Answer (score 2):

When using [javafx-maven-plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) you can specify it in your pom.xml like this:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
  <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>8.6.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <appName>Aaa Working Title</appName>
    ...
  </configuration>
  ...
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware of two methods of achieving what you want:

1) Call `javafx.awt.Desktop.getDesktop` from the main thread before creating any stages:

```
object MYAPP
{
  def main(args: Array[String]) =
  {
    val d = java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop

    // ...optionally, add handlers for interesting desktop events

    javafx.application.Application.launch(classOf[MyApp], args: _*)
  }
}
```

I believe, among other things, this renames the application menu to MYAPP.

2) Package your application using the `javapackager` tool.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can change it very easily by using the java-command args
`-Xdock:name=SomeName`

This works fine for me, launching a JavaFX application on a Java11 custom-built runtime with a bash-script as a native application.

From the Oracles Java 10 documentation:

> -Xdock:name=application name
>    Overrides the default application name displayed in dock. [*]
>
> -Xdock:icon=path to icon file
>    Overrides the default icon displayed in dock.

[*] Also affects the menu name.

You can see my complete command by looking for 'src_macos/tmpl/George.sh' here: https://bitbucket.org/andante-george/george-application/src

For the About-dialog simply do do:
`java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().setAboutHandler(my_about_handler)`.
In your handler open whatever kind of dialog or window you want.

Comment: IIRC, I needed a way to change it at runtime after the app started.

Answer (score -4):

That should work as is always worked for me :D

primaryStage.setTitle("LOLOLOLOL");

This changes your window's name.
You can change this value at any time, if you have the `Stage` element at your disposal.