# Windows Eclipse Java - How do I override "Java(TM) Platform SE binary" as OS name of my app?

Tags: java, windows, eclipse

I'm teaching Math w/Java with Windows Eclipse (NEON.3 running under Win 7).  When I use the launch button in the Eclipse control bar, the app is launched, with Windows displaying the app's name as "Java(TM) Platform SE binary".

How do I customize this default name given to the app being launched?  Who is telling Windows to use this name for the app?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the JFrame title](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487615/changing-the-jframe-title)

Comment: This is NOT a question about how to name the title bar of a window spawned by the app.  It is rather how to control the name shown by the Windows OS when you hover over the app's icon in the running-apps task bar.

Comment: You need to modify the metadata attributes of `java.exe` (look it up into your `<jdk>\bin` directory) with a proper tool. Look for "windows resource editors". Remember to back it up before to recover it later.

Comment: You may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857837/change-the-application-name-at-runtime-on-mac-for-a-javafx-based-app useful.  Even though it’s about OS X, it applies to Windows as well.