# Set JavaFX App Name with Maven in Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, maven, javafx

I developed an application and I want to set the App name (the one you see in the Mac OS X menu bar) somehow. I found this answer ([Change the application name at runtime on Mac for a JavaFX-based App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857837/change-the-application-name-at-runtime-on-mac-for-a-javafx-based-app/40324585#40324585)), so I tried to use the JavaFX Maven Plugin and this is the pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>amachine</groupId>
<artifactId>A-Machine</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <finalName>A-Machine</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>8.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>a_machine.MainGUI</mainClass>
                <appName>A-Machine</appName>
                <jfxMainAppJarName>A-Machine.jar</jfxMainAppJarName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>create-jfxjar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build-jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>a_machine.MainGUI</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Finally I use `mvn jfx:jar` to create the jar, but on the menu bar the App name is still "java".

Any ideas why?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not opening this on the github-project? Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer of that project

Answer (score 0):

`<appName>` is ment for the native launcher, you are just creating some executable JAR-file.

Please call `mvn jfx:native` to create the native launcher, with that you should get the changed Application Title.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I didn't know that. Is it possible to set the Application Title even for a jar?

Comment: Despite of "setTitle" for the window, I'm not aware of a solution, but I'm no Mac-user :) sry, maybe you will have to search for a generic "java mac application title", which is not subject of javafx

Comment: I did, but the solutions I found worked only for Swing. Anyway thank you for answering! :)